# Apply like Wildcard on Greater or Less Varchar Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table called **myTable** two varchar columns called **ValueFrom** and **ValueTo** and input something like:

```
declare @searchFrom vharchar(10)
declare @searchTo vharchar(10)
```

myTable would look like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      ValueFrom      |     ValueTo      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         cat1        |      dog2        |
|         cat2        |      dog3        |
|         cat3        |      dog4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

To search value in between, i usually use:

```
SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE ValueFrom >= @searchFrom AND ValueTo <= @searchTo
```

But now requirement is need to apply wild card to ValueFrom and ValueTo. So user will fill @search partially. Then need to apply something like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE ValueFrom LIKE '@searchFrom%' AND ValueTo LIKE '@searchTo%'
```

by looking from myTable. if i specify:

```
@searchFrom >= 'cat1' and @searchTo <= 'dog3'
```

will show 2 record. But how if

```
@searchFrom >= 'cat' and @searchTo <= 'dog'
```

I am not sure if can select value wildcard but also apply using logic greater and less. I want it to select value in between even input is only partial. Or can this be applied using between?

I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Please add excpedted result. It will be useful to help

Comment: Do you need the wildcard? A value like `'I like burgers'` is "greater than `'I like'` and is "less than `'When it rains'`. The wildcard feels like it muddies it. Also, wildcards can only be used when matching patterns; which isn't what you are doing here. The requirement doesn't make any sense.

Comment: hi. i have set some example. hope it would explain

Comment: @GhesaBhakti . . . Your question is not clear.  It does not make sense (at least to me) how to interpret `LIKE` patterns in the context of an inequality.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you mean by greater or less in your question here...  What are you expecting or wanting when you do `@searchFrom >= 'cat' and @searchTo <= 'dog'` based on the sample data provided?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(valuefrom varchar(100), valueto varchar(100));

insert into @t(valuefrom, valueto)
values
('cat1', 'dog2'), ('cat2', 'dog3'), ('cat3', 'dog4');


declare @searchFrom varchar(100)
declare @searchTo varchar(100)

select @searchFrom = 'cat', @searchTo = 'dog';

select *
from @t
where valuefrom >= @searchFrom
and valueto <= @searchTo+'z';

--if @searchFrom = 'cat', @searchTo = 'dog3' should return only cat2-dog3 (ie. LIKE is of higher precedence than <, >)
--then instead of:
select @searchFrom = 'cat', @searchTo = 'dog3'

select *
from @t
where valuefrom >= @searchFrom
and valueto <= @searchTo+'z';

--...this:

select @searchFrom = 'cat', @searchTo = 'dog3'

select *
from @t
where valuefrom like @searchFrom+'%'
and valueto like @searchTo+'%'
and valuefrom >= @searchFrom
and valueto <= @searchTo+'z';
```